Which type of ANOVA is the right choice?
I have a data set as follows and I'm wondering how: (i) this should be organised for an ANOVA test and (ii) which ANOVA (two-way mixed, two-way repeated measures) test is the correct one.
| Subject | Initial Measurement | T1 Treatment A | T1 Treatment B | T2 Treatment A | T2 Treatment B |
| ------- | ------------------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
|    1.   |       0.002.        |    0.004.      |      0.006.    |    0.004.      |      0.006.    |
|    2.   |.      0.004.        |    0.008.      |.     0.002.    |    0.008.      |.     0.002.    |

I have an initial measurement for each subject and then four other measurements at T1 and T2 where EACH subject has been subjected to both treatments A and B.
I'd really appreciate some advice and how to format these data for use with the test. I'm planning on using the Pingouin python package if that helps.

Welcome to CV.  I would not use any kind of ANOVA. ANOVA methods for repeated measures assume sphericity and no missing data, which are not usually reasonable. I would use a multilevel model.   Did you consider these?

Thanks @PeterFlom. I didn't look at multi-level models and I'm afraid I wouldn't know where to start. Are there any guides/tutorials appropriate to my use case that you could recommend?

There are tons of articles and books. I haven't looked at the literature in years, so I don't know what the best current recommendation is.  You could browse this tag and see what you find.
